# How to start Android project

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm beginner in Android development (but I have developed in Xamarin for Android). I downloaded project from:

https://github.com/zxing/zxing

and I'm trying to start it. I downloaded Android Studio 2.2.3 and opened the project. My Run and AVD manager buttons are grey, so I'm unable to start it. What should I do?

[image]

When I click Run -> Run... Edit configuration dialog is shown:

[image]

and after choosing it:

[image]

my Run button is grey.

Comment: Perhaps it's better to start with your own project and understand app configurations before jumping into somebody elses

Comment: start from here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Answer (score 0):

At first start a new project and check if Run and AVD buttons work or not.
and also becareful about Red lines in project, because they are error. you have to fix them

Comment: I tried to created new project and started it successfully

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create an AVD by clicking on AVD Manager.
Tools > Android > AVD Manager.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Under Tools I don't have Android. There is AVD Manager icon in toolbar, but it is grey.

Comment: In my opinion, the problem might be due to gradle. It may not have installed correctly try re-installing it.Make sure the Android Studio installs the gradle when you first start and create a project.     I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to run a library project. You should create a new project and add this as a dependency and use the library features in your Activities.

*ZXing ("zebra crossing") is an open-source, multi-format 1D/2D barcode image processing library implemented in Java* https://github.com/zxing/zxing